# Center icon without absolute or relative positioning?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, positioning, font-awesome

I'm trying to center an Font Awesome icon on an img. But my markup isn't positioned absolute or relative without, but layout is done with flexbox.

I've inserted the icon with CSS Attribute selector:

```
a[href*="youtu"]::before {
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    content: "\f144";
    font-size: 2.5em;
}
```

And here is the markup:

```
<div id="lightgallery">
  <a href="http://local.wordpress.dev/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/image10.jpg"> 
    <img src="http://local.wordpress.dev/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/image10.jpg" alt="" /> 
  </a>
  <a href="http://local.wordpress.dev/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/image9.jpg"> 
    <img src="http://local.wordpress.dev/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/image9.jpg" alt="" /> 
  </a>
  <a href="http://local.wordpress.dev/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/image8.jpg"> 
    <img src="http://local.wordpress.dev/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/image8.jpg" alt="" /> 
  </a>
  <a href="https://youtu.be/5Z3Exfzz8Kk" data-poster="http://local.wordpress.dev/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/video-thumb.jpg"> 
    <img src="http://local.wordpress.dev/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/video-thumb.jpg" alt="" /> 
  </a>
```

And the css:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 48em) {
  #lightgallery a {
    width: calc(100% / 3);
    height: 240px;
  }

  #lightgallery img {
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url();
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 240px;
    object-fit: cover;
  }

  #lightgallery {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin: 6.25em 0;
  }
}
```

But I can't get the icon centered over the YouTube image. I can get it centered vertically by setting attribute selector to `display: flex;` and `justify-content: center;`. And that is as far as I can come.

Any ideas to achieve this without changing the markup?

Comment: Try this https://jsfiddle.net/p2eLvmgj/ but it still use position: absolute;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you can't do it without absolute positioning. Code below can help you.

```
#lightgallery a {
    width: calc(100% / 3);
    height: 240px;

    text-decoration: none;
    position: relative;    
}

a[href*="youtu"]::before {
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    content: "\f144";
    font-size: 2.5em;

    position: absolute;      
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;             
    height: 100%;            
    display: flex;             
    justify-content: center;  
    align-items: center;     
}
```

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/95zbsh36/2/)**

Comment: You can also position center with less code: `position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%);`

Comment: @Petroff Yes, we can =)

Comment: @3rdthemagical thanks. it worked. I just had to `#lightgallery img` and `#lightgallery a` to `position: relative`